# Login form working not working when files move from localhost to serv

Tags: php, html, mysql

I devloped the follwoing code in my system In my localhost everything is working perfectly

But When I try to move files from localhost to server login form is not working properly

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'config.php';
if(isset($_POST['sub']))
{
$myusername=$_POST['txtuname']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['txtpwd']; 
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM member WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "members.php"

$_SESSION['myusername']=$myusername;
if(isset($_SESSION['myusername']))
header("location:members.php");
}
else {
echo "<b><div style=\"color:red;\">Invalid Username or Password</div></b>";

}
}
?>

Html
-----
<form name="reg" action="" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
                        Username
                        <br><input type="text" name="txtuname"><br>
                        Password 
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" name="txtpwd"><br>
                        <input type="submit" value="Login" name="sub"><br>
                        <a href="forgot.php">Lost your password?</a>
                    </form>


members.php
----------
<?php
session_start();
$sid=$_SESSION['myusername'];
if($_SESSION['myusername']=="")
{
header("location:index.php");
}
?>
```

### config.php

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost'); // Mysql hostname, usually localhost
define('DB_USERNAME', 'dbuser'); // Mysql username
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'dbpass'); // Mysql password
define('DB_DATABASE', 'dbname'); // Mysql database name
$connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());
$database = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

All above code is working perfectly in my XAMPP Server
But when I move these files from localhost to server that time login form is not working properly

When I entered correct username, password it is not redirected to the members.php

If  I enter Username and password as wrong it shows invalid username password message

Please help me anyone where is the mistake

Comment: what error message you get?

Comment: check your db connection for your wenserver

Comment: Error msg is "Invalid Username or Password" If I enter wrong username or password

Comment: as per our above comment 'what do you want to do?' allow user to login even if they enter wrong username or password ?

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't seeing any errors, you may have PHP error reporting disabled. In the head of your PHP file, insert this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Also, append  `or die mysql_error();` to all your DB queries. For example:

```
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

I would recommend looking into the following:

1. Check database credentials
2. Make sure you have your database in place with data within in... not just an empty table
3. Look into any errors that appear when running the file
4. Try your code on another server if available... or even set it up again in another folder and use a different database and see if you can get it running the exact same way locally.

Comment: even this is not the answer but i think eventually the OP has to follow these steps. +1

Comment: I just noticed there is no `mysql_connect` statement. It's probably in the config.php file. They should run queries referencing their mysql resource. ie. 
`$db = mysql_connect( ... ) or die(mysql_error());` 
and then
`$r = mysql_query($sql,$db) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Hi ahmed,wat u said above disable things no where I use In my script But still the problem exist I checked my database credentials also those are fine

Comment: Did you check your member table on the server? See if you have any user records in there.

Comment: Yes I checked member table is exist and have few records